# assigning a JSON object as field value using JOLT in NIFI

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have an attribute **"TEST"** storing a JSON object, I tried this JOLT but I'm getting

> "**Unable to marshal json to an object**"

error

**TEST**:

```json
[
  {
    "ORDER_DATE": "2022-04-11",
    "TIME_STAMP": "1667543037000"
  },
  {
    "ORDER_DATE": "2022-05-05",
    "TIME_STAMP": "1651741666000"
  }
]
```

**JOLT Transformation** :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "TIMESTAMP": "timeStamp"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "product": "Billing Account CMT Update",
      "team": "${TEST}"
    }
  }
]
```

**Expected Output** :

```
{
  "product": "Billing Account CMT Update",
  "team": [
    {
      "ORDER_DATE": "2022-04-11",
      "TIME_STAMP": "1667543037000"
    },
    {
      "ORDER_DATE": "2022-05-05",
      "TIME_STAMP": "1651741666000"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Edit 1**: It can probably be possible with ***ReplaceText*** processor but I want pure JOLT solution

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "team[]"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "product": "Billing Account CMT Update"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: This doesn't have mention of the attribute 'TEST' anywhere in it. I don't believe this is the solution

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you get that error due to the fact that the

*com.fasterxml.jackson.core*.***`JsonParseException`***

is raised, cause the attribute must be passed as a string while the JSON value contains some unquoted characters.

In that case, you might convert

the part `"team":"${TEST}"` to **`"team":"${TEST:escapeJson()}"`**

in order to get rid of the issue.

Comment: tried it same error sadly